# Mixed models: No significant interaction - post-hoc analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, post-hoc

I have a more or less general question about the logic of post-hoc-tests: I did a mixed linear model on the effect of a treatment on well-being. Subjects were randomly assigned to one of two treatment conditions (A or B). The second factor included in the analysis was measurement point (t0,t1,t2,t3). I had two hypothesises:

1. Treatments differ in their change in well-being over time --> I assume the interaction effect Time x Treatment to be significant.
2. At t2, subjects who received treatment A will score higher on well-being than subjects receiving treatment B --> I assume post-hoc-analysis to detect significant differences between A and B at t2

Results indicated that there is no significant interaction between Time and Treatment. Should I still calculate and refort post-hoc analysis to examine the second hypothesis, or would this be redundant, as there is no evidence for groups to differ in well-being over time?

Comment: Please clarify the language. By "measurement point", don't you really mean "measurement time"?  By "I assume", don't you really mean "I hypothesize"? And the hypothesis is about the actual differences not about "significant" conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. So I hypothesize the interaction effect measurement time x treatment to be significant. It turned out not to be. So I was wodnering wether I still should calculate contrasts/post-hoc analysis for t2

Comment: Let me try rewording: Your scientific hypothesis is that the effect of treatment is different at different times and you want to compute that difference with a confidence interval. But the ANOVA interaction P value is greater than 0.05 so your data are consistent (P > 0.05) with equal treatment effects at all time points. Is it still worth doing followup "post hoc' tests?